# cross forward declarations in template classes/functions

Tags: c++, templates

I get two heads:
header1:

```
#ifndef CPPSH_A_H
#define CPPSH_A_H
class B;
class A {
 public:
  template<typename T>
  void Function1() {
    b_->Function2<int>();
  }
  template<typename T>
  void Function2() {

  }
 private:
  B* b_;
};
#endif //CPPSH_A_H
```

and header2:

```
#ifndef CPPSH_B_H
#define CPPSH_B_H
class A;
class B {
 public:
  template<typename T>
  void Function1() {
    a_->Function2<int>();
  }
  template<typename T>
  void Function2() {

  }
 private:
  A* a_;
};
#endif //CPPSH_B_H
```

and you can see that both `a_` and `b_` is incomplete type, and the calls on it is invaild.
if these two classes are normal classes, I can move the `Test()` implementation to source file, and then include the proper header.

But since template classes/functions must define and declare their implementation in headers, how to deal this problem?

Comment: You can merge the two headers into one; then the problem is infinite recursion on `Test()`..

Comment: This example seems not very appropriate, let me edit

Comment: You have declared four different classes: `A`, `A::B`, `B`, and `B::A`. Not what you meant to do?

Comment: @aschepler fixed, thanks for point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the two headers into one, e.g.

```
// forward declaration
class B; 
class A {
 public:
  // member function template declaration
  template<typename T>
  void Function1();
  template<typename T>
  void Function2() {
  }
 private:
  B* b_;
};

class B {
 public:
  template<typename T>
  void Function1() {
    a_->Function2<T>();
  }
  template<typename T>
  void Function2() {
  }
 private:
  A* a_;
};

// member function template definition
template<typename T>
void A::Function1() {
  b_->Function2<T>();
}
```